# UITableView in UIViewController reloadData not updating table view

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, reloaddata

I have my MainViewController which a UIViewController class, in this view I have a table view and another view embedded in it. As you can see I added the table view delegates to the view controller.

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate,   UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
```

Now to my question which has been asked about 50 times from multiple searches on the internet but still I have not been able to find a solution.

Why doesn't reloadData work...?

I am downloading info from an XML feed and I refresh the feed from the app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

I have inserted multiple NSLogs, this is what I have found. The refreshed data from the XML feed is coming in no problem. But the table view cells are not being refreshed.

I placed a NSLog in:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
```

Although the data is being refreshed, when I call [tableView reloadData]; the cellForRowAtIndexPath is never called.

I am hoping someone can help me with this issue, I have been working on this issue for about 12 hours with no luck. I have exhausted the search button on multiple sites....

FYI:
-Table View is wired in Interface Builder.

-My tables are being loaded one by one via TableViewCells, following Apples example starting on page 51 of the Table View Programming guide.

Additional Code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return 17;
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is working now... That was a lot of time wasted on my part...

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
[_mainViewController refresh];
[_mainViewController.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)refresh {
Parser *xmlParser = [[Parser alloc] init];
[xmlParser parseRssFeed:@"http://www.somesite.com/file.xml" withDelegate:self];
[xmlParser release];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any example Code ?

My first ideas:

- Datasource not connected
- Rows in Section give 0 back
- Sections give 0 back

Comment: Mafis, I have added some additional code above regarding the items you mentioned. My table view datasource and delegate are wired to the files owner in the XIB file.